# return a value from object in js

Tags: javascript

Assume I have a simple object in js with one private variable:

```
function test(){
var value=true;
}
```

and now I want to create one instance:

```
var r=new test() //I want to get r === true
```

How can I return a value from it?

If I write:

```
function test(){
var value=true;

return value;
}
```

I have a test {} in result.

If I write:

```
function test(){
var value=true;

return function(){ return value; } 
}
```

then I can get the value, but I must add additional parentheses:

var r=new test()() //r === true

I don't want the parentheses, so I tried to change the code to:

```
function test(){
var value=true;

return (function(){ return value; } )();
}
```

But in response, again I get test {}
How to write the return statement in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I feel obliged to clarify a possible misunderstanding:

```
function test(){
    var value=true;
}
```

is not an object with a private variable. It is a **function** with a local variable. When you call the function with `new`, it **creates** an object inheriting from the functions's prototype with no properties. If you call the function normally, it simply executes the function body and returns `undefined` (since you are not returning anything).

---

### Solutions:

Do you actually need a constructor function? I'm asking because your example is very simple.  Obviously you cannot have the function return two values, `true` and the object.

So, you could just call the function without `new`:

```
function test() {
    var value = true;
    return value;
}

var r = test();
```

If you really want `r` to be `true` then I see no reason to call the function as a constructor function.

The reason why you got `test {}` as result was because you called the function with `new`. If you do that, the function will *always* return an object and if you don't do so explicitly (`value` is a boolean, not an object), it implicitly returns `this` (which is an object).
So again, if you really want `r` to be equal to `value` from inside the function, then simply don't call the function with `new`.

---

If you need an object though, there are a couple of ways:

You can assign the value to a property and access it instead, like [PokeHerOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603018/pokeherone) showed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12248817/218196) or add a function which returns that value, as [papaiatis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675462/papaiatis) [demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12248877/218196). The advantage is that the value is accessed explicitly and other people looking at your code understand what's going on.

Additionally, depending on what you want to do with that value / object, you can implement the `valueOf` methods, which gets called by various operators.

For example:

```
function Test(){
    var value = true;

    this.valueOf = function() {
        return value;
    }
}

var t = new Test();
console.log(t);          // logs the Test instance
console.log(t == true);  // logs `true`
```

I.e. `t` is an object but behaves like the value `true` (`value`) in various operations. This is powerful but can also be quite confusing, since the type conversion is somewhat implicit and it's not something that is used in JavaScript very often.

Comment: Great answer! Would give you more than just +1 if I could. Thank you for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to do something like:

```
function test(){
    this.value = true;
}
```

and then

```
var r=new test();
if (r.value == true) {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: He wants the `value` to be private. This is not private declaration.

Comment: I think he didn't mean it to be private from the first example but could make it like this:


var test = (function(){
 var value = true;
 
 return value;
})();    I don't know how to put it in code formatting but, oh well you get it

Answer (score 0):

Used methods defined internally:

```
function TestClass(){
    var value = true;
    this.getValue = function(){
        return value;
    };
}

var t = new TestClass();
alert(t.getValue()); // true
```

Since `value` is defined as private it is not accessible from outside:

```
alert(t.value) // undefined
```